# Mensagem do navegador após requisição AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho uma requisição ajax responsável por enviar um arquivo para a servlet, ela esta realizando o processo corretamente. Porém quando vou atualizar a pagina a seguinte mensagem é exibida pelo navegador (Quando dou um f5):

> A pagina que você esta procurando usou informações inseridas.Voltar à essa pagina poderá fazer com que todas as ações realizadas sejam repedidas. Deseja Continuar ?

Não quero que essa mensagem apareça para meus usuários.

Requisição ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#formAv").submit(function(event) {
        var dados = new FormData(this);
        var url = "Avatar";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            data: dados,
            mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
        });
    });
});
```

OBS: A mensagem é do próprio navegador, tentei limpar o formulário depois do envio mas não resolveu.

Comment: Se estás a fazer o submit via ajax devias ter `event.preventDefault();` dentro dessa função, antes de `var dados` por exemplo.

Comment: Obrigado, pela resposta deu certo! Só lembrando que o type é POST, eu me engane na hora de colar o código.

Answer (score 2):

Esse aviso que o browser dá só acontece quando submetes um formulário via API do HTML. Ou seja, usando a `<form action=""`. Uma vez que estás a usa ajax, deves cancelar o envio da form via API do HTML e submeter, como estás a fazer via ajax.

Para cancelar a acção natural podes fazer com `event.preventDefault()`. Nesse caso o teu código podia ser assim:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#formAv").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var dados = new FormData(this);
        var url = "Avatar";
```